# Google Earth Engine: How do I create a feature collection with bounded, randomly-assigned classes?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, feature-collection

Here's an example script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d511144dde609f4cf1fd8607499e2026

I would like to create a set of random points with random classes to use as training data in order to generate and evaluate a null distribution.
The .randomColumn function only gives values between 0-1. To get random classes, I need uniformly distributed integers from 0 to 3, but it does not look like Feature Collections support the kind of math required to manipulate .randomColumn() like that.

My next thought is .randomPoints(), but I am unfamiliar with its use. If I use .randomPoints() to create a random Feature Collection to use as null training data, how do I:

1. Make sure the points are only on land/unmasked area?
2. Make sure the points don't overlap with the existing validation data?
3. Add random feature classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got image masks involved, the easiest way is to generate a random image (multiply by 4 and round down), mask it with your valid/land mask, and sample it with `stratifiedSample`.  That'll make sure you don't sample points from places you don't want and give you fine control over number of points and how close they are to each other (via scale).

```
var source = ee.Image.random().multiply(4).int()
    .updateMask(mask)
    .stratifiedSample({
      numPoints: 1000, 
      region: geometry, 
      scale: 1000, 
      geometries: true})
```

That said, your original question about how to create random classes on a feature collection is with randomPoints + randomColumn() and mapping over the collection to do whatever math you want to with random number.  Something like:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, 1000)
    .randomColumn()
    .map(function(f) {
      return f.set("class", f.getNumber('random').multiply(4).int())
    })
```

Comment: The first one did the trick, thanks!